# resource for practical javascript exercise

Tags: javascript

I am beginner to webprogramming &  Javascript. I have went through few tutorials and learned the basics. Could someone suggest me the best resource with practical exercise with solutions.

I found "pagetutor.com" which has practical javascript exercises, but it's paid! Please
suggest any paid sites too which is really worth for practical learning.

Comment: The best resources to learn about JavaScript (not practice it) are the MDC JavaScript [Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) and [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference). For practical exercise: Be a bit creative and think about an application you could implement. E.g. a simple email viewer (must not access real emails) utilizing Ajax and DOM manipulation. Or some more fancy stuff using third party APIs such as Google Maps...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html) is an "interactive tutorial" that embeds an editor directly into its pages, enabling you to test and experiment with its many examples.
- [Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) provides a series of examples intended to enable the learner to understand Prototype.js's `.bind` method.  Examples can be edited to allow the reader to experiment with them.

Admittedly, neither of these options actually provide an answer to the question, as they are not really "exercises" so much as interactive tutorials.  But they may be of some value nonetheless.

Comment: I would also like to add http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/
They have A LOT of great exercises for beginners.

Answer (score 6):

I would have to say that http://javascript.crockford.com/ is one of the most important resources when learning (correct) JavaScript. Perhaps not as the first stop, but definitely when you've gotten the hang of the basics.

Answer (score 5):

This online free [eloquent javascript book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is awesome. But not much practical exercises.

Answer (score 5):

I learned that from books. 
Basics: [W3schools javaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

For advanced I suggest these books:
[Advanced JavaScript(TM), Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004L2KRRY)
[Pro JavaScript Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597273)

[Professional JavaScript for Web Developers (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047022780X)

Books are cheap :)

Also I bought W3Schools books about HTML, JavaScript and CSS and I like it :)

Comment: Also for you, have a look at http://w3fools.com/ to rethink about w3schools.

Comment: I saw that now. That is terrible. On my luck I didn't have problems with html,css and php which w3schools presents. I`m myself learner of html, css, php, and I use books from Amazon to improve my knowledge. Basics of JavaScript I learned from w3schools and now I know why I have always questions about JS. GOD DAMN!
Wrost case is that you learn advanced when basic knowledge is poor.

Answer (score 4):

One great source is : [Code academy](http://www.codecademy.com/).
You are learning javascript by writing code step by step and solving small exercises.

Answer (score 2):

you could try http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp. it's a very basic intro to the language.

Also I would recommend [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996)

very nice book, describes the language in details.

Also Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

And probably some good blogs:

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/

http://net.tutsplus.com/

http://www.webappers.com/

for exercise I would recommend [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: Do you know http://w3fools.com/ ? If not, time to have a look at it ;)

Comment: Nope, I didn't know about it :D. thanks.